# action mailer and url generation in Rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

So I realize that Rails mailers need help in generating urls.  I want HTML email with images served externally (no attachments) so I've set both:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000
```

and two things happen in my mailer template:

1. It hates the use of image_tag.  Just barfs with an action view template error
2. url_for does nothing for unnamed routes.  shouldn't it prepend the asset_host? for assets in public?